# Regex groups confusion with some text

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have some input text like the following:

```
Oracle SQL 19c
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
Microsoft SQL Server 2016
MySQL 8.2
```

And this regex:

```
(^.*\s)+(\d+\.?\d+\s?)?(.*)?
```

The regex works just fine with all the phrases in the above list.
For example:

##### Microsoft SQL Server 2016

```
Group 1: Microsoft SQL Server 
Group 2: 2012
Group 3: ""
```

However, the `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2` is not working as I would expect:

This phrase, is grouped as:

```
Match 1: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
Group 1: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 
Group 3: R2
```

I cannot understand why group 2 is not shown! What is wrong with my regex?
Note that the strings always contain a number preceded with a whitespace.

Comment: Maybe something like `^(.*?) (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) ?(.*)` will help?

Comment: A general advise: Try to avoid `(.*)?` - they can match anything and are hard to understand (as you have just experienced). Instead be more specific in your search.

Comment: For the record and if anyone finds this: @WiktorStribiżew's answer did the trick for me!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so you added the `(?:\.\d+)` as a non-capturing group. What is the reasoning behind it.
(Generally, I would like to see your post as an answer to give you the +1 and to also understand it better, if you can want/can of course)

Comment: @ptselios Yeah, `\d+\.?\d+` won't match `0`, it requires two digits.

Comment: @ptselios If you have found an answer (not a comment) that works for you, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion I provided in the comments was based on the assumption that your strings always contain a number, possibly followed by an optional period + some more digits, always preceded with a space. The problem with your regex is that all its parts are optional, so the first `.*` grabs all the text it can, and since there is an obligatory `\s` after `.*` it is doomed to match till last whitespace and the rest is matched with the last greedy `.*` (adding `?` after `(.*)` does not make it lazy).

So, the suggested pattern looks like

```
^(.*?)\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(.*)
```

It matches like this:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible (lazy dot pattern)
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 2: one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits (note that `\d+\.?\d+` requires the presence of at least 2 consecutive digits!)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (greedy dot pattern).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gu3ukh/1) (`\s` are replaced with spaces since the demo pattern is run against multiple lines, not a single multiline string).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
Essentially, capture everything up to a *digit*, which may optionally be followed by text.

```
^(.+?)\s(\d+(?:.+?$)?)
```

```
Oracle SQL, 19c
Microsoft SQL Server, 2008 R2
Microsoft SQL Server, 2016
MySQL, 8.2
Microsoft SQL Server, 2008 R2
```